# Stockfish: Engine suddenly changed the side?

Tags: engines, stockfish, uci

I asked this question in stockfishchess.org support but didn't get any response. So I'm trying to get some answers from you all.

My question:

Please find the output of communication with the engine [here](http://support.stockfishchess.org/discussions/problems/8262/assets/8699536f356332751f589175b63647d95716c3fa/output.txt). (It has only 8 steps.) The last best move (`bestmove c5d4 ponder f3d4`) is not for white, but for black.

Am I doing something wrong here or has engine confused for some reason? Appreciate your help to understand.

Original question link: 
http://support.stockfishchess.org/discussions/problems/8262-engine-suddenly-changed-the-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is very simple:

> position startpos moves e2e4 d7d6 d2d4 e7e6 g1f3 c8d7 f1d3 h7h6 e1g1 c7c5 f1e1 e8f8

This is invalid. The position before `e8f8` is:

[image]

`e8f8` is invalid because Black has a bishop on f8. Stockfish can't play the move, so it just skip it.

To Stockfish, the diagram position is the position it's thinking. The best move is `...cxd4`.

Comment: Oh too bad I missed that. Thank you very much.